# amazon associates: how well does it perform

Tags: advertising, amazon

I'm thinking about adding some amazon associates affiliate links to one of my sites, and I'm wondering if anyone who has any experience with them can tell me how well they perform on their site. Also, amazon associates offers several advertising widgets: can anyone tell me which one performs the best (brings in the most revenue)?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have some of the least generous cookie and commission rates out there, but I've done ok with Amazon.  I don't really promote it any more, but I still get a steady trickle of purchases, and it's very common for people to buy other things in the same sale.

Personally I found most of their pre-made widgets and searches didn't perform - I got a little traffic through them, but not enough to justify their space on the page - what *did* work for me was a direct, specific link to a book I that was related to the context of the particular page it was on.  So their oldest affiliate link type basically.